# Ios 6.1 to ios 7 even if there is already 7.1.1

Tags: ios, ipad, upgrade

Is it posible to update to ios 7 from ios 6.1 for ipad 4 even if there is update for ios 7.1.1

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128424/can-i-update-from-ios-6-1-3-to-ios-7-but-not-ios-7-1

Comment: iOS 7.1.1 is iOS7... Do you mean iOS 7.0?

Answer (score 1):

No - it is Apple philosophy to disallow older updates. If you update, then you must (!) update to the newest system.

Same for downgrades - you are not allowed to downgrade to a older system if you dislike the updated version.

Buy the way: why do you want to upgrade to 7.0 and not 7.1.1?